# Applying function to specific columns while preserving other

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function to center my data:

```
    center_colmeans <- function(x) {
      xcenter = colMeans(x)
      x - rep(xcenter, rep.int(nrow(x), ncol(x)))
    }
  
   mtcars$cyl <- as.character(mtcars$cyl)
   center_colmeans(mtcars)
```

This runs fine if I remove cyl (since it's a string). such as this:

```
   center_colmeans(mtcars[4:8])
```

But I want to run "center_colmeans" on all numeric variables, while preserving cyl as it is. In my data, I have multiple string columns that I won't to preserve as is. I need them in my final data set with the centered means. Any idea's appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a logical vector where the columns are `numeric` ('i1'), use that to subset the 'mtcars' and apply the function

```
i1 <- sapply(mtcars, is.numeric)
mtcars[i1] <- center_colmeans(mtcars[i1])
```

Comment: Akrun is too quick, I think he has an `R` parser in his head.

Comment: @akrun Thank you! Wish I had a tenth of your skill!